# Is side-loading apps onto a Windows RT device allowed?

Tags: windows-8

Is it possible to side-load a Windows 8 app (WinRT) onto a Windows RT device like the new Microsoft Surface RT? For example, if I have an internal, line of business application can I give a Microsoft Surface RT to my executives and load up my corporate apps without delivering them through the Windows Store?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will metro-style apps be able to be installed outside the market frame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264451/will-metro-style-apps-be-able-to-be-installed-outside-the-market-frame)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712563/will-it-be-possible-to-install-an-app-to-the-surface-without-passing-from-micros

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**. Side-loading is natively supported on:

1. Windows RT
2. Windows 8 Pro
3. Windows 8 Enterprise

And, side-loading is enabled with Visual Studio on:

4. Windows 8 Core

Enterprises can deploy apps using Microsoft Configuration Manager just like they deploy desktop apps today. Enterprises can also uses Microsoft Intune and its Windows 8 Self-Service Portal (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/04/19/managing-quot-byo-quot-pcs-in-the-enterprise-including-woa.aspx) app to securely deliver apps to devices, too.

Considering this? Here's an interesting article about W8 tablet security: http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Windows-8-Tablets-Secure-enough-Enterprise.html

Like to read? Here's more info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/04/25/deploying-metro-style-apps-to-businesses.aspx

Comment: NB: Sideloading is supported for RT devices, but it's not free. You need to purchase a sideloading activation key though volume licensing, as this article (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/jj874388.aspx?ocid=wc-nl-insider) mentions. Rocky Lhotka did an analysis of the costs: http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/CostToEnableSideloadingOnAWindows8Device.aspx

Comment: And just to save some people the reading ... the *minimum* cost is **$3,000** for 100 side-loading license keys.

Answer (score 1):

Some more resources

[Private Enterprise App Deployment for Windows 8](http://blogs.telerik.com/mehfuz-hossain/posts/13-04-16/private-enterprise-app-deployment-for-windows-8)

[Try It Out: Sideload Windows Store Apps](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/jj874388.aspx?ocid=wc-nl-insider)

[Sideloading Windows 8 Store Apps](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/springboard/archive/2013/02/21/sideloading-windows-8-store-apps.aspx)

Comment: Great resources, Farhan. Thanks for including them.