# How do I deploy my customer specific app without use of the appstore

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store, dynamics-nav

I am looking for a simple method to deploy my app by my customer without use of the Microsoft AppStore. This because this app is a part of an bigger solution, the data source for this app is data from Microsoft Dynamics NAV (which is not default NAV), so I don't want this downloadable for the public and it only works in combination with my NAV software. Maybe that the AppStore has a feature for this that I don't know of, but I did not find it.

Comment: related: [Is side-loading apps onto a Windows RT device allowed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922935/is-side-loading-apps-onto-a-windows-rt-device-allowed)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is sideloading. In order to sideload for a customer, the customer needs a sideloading license. [You can check out more about sideloading here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj874388.aspx).

In Windows 8.1, they improved the sideloading functionality quite a bit, including expanding the ability to sideload to all Windows 8.1 Pro licenses (instead of just Enterprise). In order to do this, they must be joined to an Active Directory domain. Otherwise, you must purchase an Enterprise Sideloading Key. More information on this can be found [here](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/springboard/archive/2014/04/03/windows-8-1-sideloading-enhancements.aspx).

Comment: Yes I also found this on the internet, but I can't assume that my customers have an AD with the deployment services.

Comment: Then they'll need to purchase an Enterprise Sideloading Key if they do not.